# How to morph a 2d grid of saturation and luminance onto the surface of a torus?

Tags: geometry, surfaces, coloring

For any given hue, we get a Cartesian grid of saturation and luminance like so:

[image]

I would like to warp this surface to the shape of a torus:

[image]

such that all the colors are **continuous**, and that there is a **one-to-one** correspondence between a point on the grid to a point on the surface of the torus. By continuous colors I mean that every path on the torus is essentially a smooth gradient of colors. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if you are willing to allow some duplication.

Reflect that square (call it `A`)  over its right and top edges to create two new squares `B` and `C` so the three form an ell shape

```
B
A C
```

Then reflect `B` or `C` to make `D`.

```
B D
A C
```

Finally, glue the horizontal and vertical edges of the new big square in the usual way to make a torus.

Comment: But can it be done without duplication? I was asking for one-to-one correspondence, meaning a point on the grid corresponds to a single point on the torus, and vice versa.

Comment: @darksky I don't think so. The topology is a real obstruction. The torus has no boundaries, so you have to do some pasting to take care of the edges of the square and there's no place light enough to paste the upper right corner to.